# Make full screen image content responsive and take up 1/3 of screen left align

Tags: html, css

I currently have the result I am looking for. However, I have not done it the most efficient way, and it is not responsive. I want the page to look exactly like this, except for when the window is resized, the elements don't freak out.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.9/components/button.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="image">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="imgContent">
                    <h1>Quer oferecer nossos vinhos em seu restaurante ou evento?</h1>
                    <div class="button">
                        <button class="massive ui inverted basic button">Entre em contato</button>
                    </div>
                    <p>Nosso objetivo e trazer para o mercado braileiro o vinho dos pequenos produtores, aqueles que utilizam, principalmente, as uvas de suas proprias terras e que fazem o vinho com paixao, sequindo a tradicao familiar, que e aperfeicoada e passada de geracao em geracao.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="content">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/*START BG IMG*/
.image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(images/home.jpeg);
  background-position: 50% 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.image h1 {
  font-family: "Playfair Display";
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-right: 56%;
}

.image p {
  font-family: "Playfair Display";
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 70%;
  line-height: 150%;
}

.button {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.imgContent {
  padding-top: 125px;
}


/*END BG IMG*/

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: So, you've included Bootstrap, but you haven't used any of Bootstrap's grid classes that would help you complete this?

Comment: Can you explain? I understand Bootstrap's grid classes. I just didn't realize I could use it on this.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Also, make sure you get rid of the absolute positioning on your elements - they're not going to be responsive that way because they've been removed from the document flow.

Comment: I am still not sure how to do all of with the bootstrap grid system. I am a little new to this.

Comment: I thought you said you understood Bootstrap's grid classes? Start by getting rid of your absolute positioning - change those to `relative`, then read the grid documentation and give it a try. Also, a reference image of what you'd like your content to look like would be nice.

Comment: Does just changing to `relative` produce what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/3uuaamt9/

Comment: I got the grid working, but changing to relative make my image not full screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "except for when the window is resized"

You can use `@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {` to control the windows resize design.

if you want your image has background why don't you use `body { background-image:`?